# Is the function complex differentiable at (0,0)?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

(in Complex)
$$  g(z) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{z^5}{|z|^4} & \text{if $z \neq 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $z = 0$ }
\end{cases} $$

For the function above, is it differentiable at $z=0$?
I am trying to use following theorem to solve it:

*Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be defined in some open set G containing the point $z_0$. If the first partial derivates of u and v exist in G, are continuous at $z_0$ and satisfy the C-R equations at $z_0$, then f is differentiable at $z_0$.*

I would say, since $g(z)=0$ if $z=0$ that C-R holds at $0$ and that first partial derivates exist in $C$, but I am not sure about the partial derivates being continuous at $0$ (how do I see that)?

Comment: why not use definition?

Comment: I really don't see how.

Comment: See [here](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/mbk-49-prev.pdf)

Comment: @Zoe I had a small typo in my answer which might be dangerous if you're too distracted. Please check the updated version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trying to use Cauchy-Riemann here won't help because the partials are not continuous. In fact this an example of a function which satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann's equations at a point but isn't differentiable there.

To prove that isn't differentiable at the origin, use the definition: $$\lim \limits_{z\to 0}\left(\dfrac{g(z)}z\right)=\lim \limits_{z\to 0}\left(\dfrac{z^4}{|z|^4}\right).$$

Now consider the $\theta$-sublimits $\lim \limits_{\rho \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\left(\rho e^{i\theta}\right) ^4}{\left|\rho e^{i\theta}\right|^4}\right)$, where $\theta\in \mathbb R$. Conclude.

Comment: i know this question is answered a long time ago, but if we take $\ro$ to zero from $0^+$ and $0^-$, dont the limits stay the same?

Kees

Comment: @KeesTil No worries. MSE is not like other forums, an old thread doesn't need to stay dead. It is implied that $\rho>0$ (I just rewrote $z$ in its trigonometric form), so $\dfrac{\left(\rho e^{i\theta}\right) ^4}{\left|\rho e^{i\theta}\right|^4}=e^{4\theta i}$ and the limit is independent of $\theta$. (...)

Comment: (...) You used the symbols $0^-$ and $0^-$. This suggests you're considering just the limits in the real axis. But this is a complex function. It could even be that the limits in the real axis were the same, but that's not enough to guarantee the limit exists. But in fact the limits are not the same and you can see that if you consider the lateral limits at $0$ of the real function $x\mapsto \dfrac{x}{|x|}$ (the fourth power doesn't matter), they do not coincide. **Edit:** I realise now you were talking about $\rho$ so you can ignore this comment, but the same idea works if you let $\rho <0$.

Comment: the fourth power does matter right. Because one can´t get $-1$ as a limit with the the fourth power.

Comment: @KeesTil Of course you're right, my bad. The rest still holds. Is there anything I can make more clear?

Comment: no i already see it, thanks for writing this out though it made me clear why it's not complex differentiable because you can choose $\theta$ in different ways which give different limits :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

Note that for $x$ real we have $g(x) = x$, so if $g$ was differentiable, we must have $g'(0) = 1$.

Now check $|{g(z)-g(0) \over z}-1| = | {z^5 \over z|z|^4} -1 | = |  {z^4-|z|^4 \over |z|^4}|$. Can this be made arbitrarily small?

Having done that, this suggests looking at $g(x e^{i {\pi \over 4}})$ (for example) for $x$ real.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g$ as a function from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$  where $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a two-dimensional vector space. Let's find the real directional derivatives at $(0,0)$.  For $z\in \mathbb{C}$ and $t >0$ we have

$$\frac{g(tz) - g(0)}{t}= \frac{(tz)^5}{|t z|^4 t}= \frac{t^5 z^5}{t^5 |z^4|} = (\frac{z}{|z|})^4 \cdot z$$

Therefore the real directional derivative in direction $z$ is $(\frac{z}{|z|})^4 \cdot z$. This function 
$$z \mapsto (\frac{z}{|z|})^4 \cdot z$$

is not an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map. Therefore, $g$ is not real differentiable at $(0,0)$, so neither complex differentiable.

Note that 
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 1\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = i$$

so $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}= i \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$
so the Cauchy-Riemann are equalities hold. The problem is that $g$ is not real differentiable at $(0,0)\ \ \ $  $\tiny{ \text{Cauchy-Riemann:} \frac{\partial g}{\partial (iy)}=  \cdot \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} }$

Obs: Let's check that the map $z \mapsto (\frac{z}{|z|})^4 \cdot z$, $0\mapsto 0$ is not additive. Indeed, $1\mapsto 1$, $i \mapsto i$ but $(1+i) \mapsto -(1+i)$.